# Why am i having an error: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined when returning an API data?

Tags: javascript

So it's actually a new question, cause my previouse one wasn't too clear and I had to delete it.
I have a function which takes an api data from parent function, and changes div contains to this api data.

Parent function:

```
function searchBook(query){
    const url = BASE_URL + `${query}` + '&' + API_KEY;

    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(books =>{
        console.log(books);
    })
    .then(books => showBooks(books.results));
```

So it fetches an api and prints it in console in promise. But in the next promise I want to invoke a function which shows books on the page by adding them to divs:

```
showBooks = books =>{
    const main = document.getElementById('book_container');
    main.innerHTML = "";
    books.forEach(book => {
        const bookEl = document.createElement('div');
        bookEl.classList.add('book');

        bookEl.innerHTML = `
        <div class="book">
        <div class="border"></div>
            <img src="img/cover.jpg">
    <div class="book_info">
            <h3>${book.title}</h3>
            <p>${book.authors}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="overview">
            <p>${book.description}</p>
    </div>
</div>
        `

        main.appendChild(bookEl);
    });
}
}
```

It should get books data from searchBooks function through '.then' promise, but for some reason it returns the next error:
[image]

So when i remove results from showBooks(books.results), it returns the next error:
[image]

[image]

For some reason data is undefined, though it's passed through promise, so I'm not sure what could be the reason.
I've searched the same approach on the internet, and it seems to work fine, but in my app it doesn't work.
It prints data in console, so data is passed after all, but for some reason it doesn't work in the showBooks function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function searchBook(query){
const url = BASE_URL + `${query}` + '&' + API_KEY;

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(books =>{
    console.log(books);
    return books;
})
.then(books => showBooks(books.results));
```

your second `.then()` need to return data to use it in your third `.then(books => showBooks(books.results))`

Comment: hi! i did return the data and it solved the error, but another error popped up as i mentioned in the answer under yours!

Comment: `books.results` is an Array? you need to check if it's an Array or you get an error. You can use the function `Array.isArray(books)`

Comment: ok i checked and it says books isn't an array, so should i convert it to an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove

```
.then(books =>{
        console.log(books);
    }
```

or make it return `books` so the next `then` has something to work with:

```
.then(books =>{
        console.log(books);
        return books;
    }
```

Comment: hi! i did just that and undefined error is gone, but another error popped up:
TypeError: books.forEach is not a function
    at showBooks
could it be that i can't use forEach?

Comment: From the images you posted it looks like `books` is an object with the following shape: `{ kind: string, totalItems: number, items: Array }`, so you probably want to iterate over those `items`: `books.items.forEach`